# Create cumulative hypsograhic curve from DEM

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a cumulative hypsometric/hypsographic curve from two digital elevation models, preferably with matplotlib.
I already read the values of the DEMs into two separate arrays and got a simple cumulative histogram with the count/frequency on the y-axis and the elevation on x. Now, I need the elevation values on the y-axis and then the percentage on the x-axis, like this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypsografische_Kurve#/media/File:Hypsografische_Kurve_der_Schweiz.png

Does someone have suggestions how to achieve this?

edit:
So far I have this:

```
f,ax = pylab.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
bins = [500.0, 1000.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2500.0, 3000.0, 3500.0, 4000.0, 4500.0, 5000.0, 5500.0, 6000.0, 6500.0]
pylab.xlabel("Elevation in [m]")
pylab.ylabel("Count")
pylab.xticks(bins)
ax.hist([height1,height], bins, rwidth=0.9, color=["r","b"], alpha=0.5, label=['dem_c','dem_t'],histtype="bar", cumulative = True)
pylab.legend(loc='upper right')
```

height and height1 are the lists containing the elevation values read from the DEMs via gdal. This is my output so far.[image]

Comment: For me, it is hard to understand what exactly you are looking for. Do you just want to swap the x- and y-axis? It would also be nice if you could provide a small excerpt of what you already programmed, i.e. how you made your cumulative histogram.

Comment: It seems you just need to exchange x for y in the plot and plot a line graph instead of a bar chart. If you have any problems with that, a clear problem description is needed (i.e. what have you tried, what was the output, in how far is the output not what you expect) together with a [mcve] of the code that does it.

Comment: Added it my current status